# ARKIT - 3d text - state of the art

Tags: arkit

request is to be able to render in arkit test input from keyboard.

So far I have used SCNText, which is 3d render of plain 2D text. I am not satisfied with that result as the text is clearly a projection in 3D space of a 2D text in X/Y plane. Also applying effects like "neon" is not effective.
The only thing pops out from my mind at the moment is to:

a- Create for every char a .DAE object representing the character
b- Import the .DAEs and map them with the characters

This approach is very time consuming and don't even know possible complications. Also considering the different languages it will involve further work to adapt to the different languages.

Questions:

1- Is anyone familiar with that and has implemented that already?
2- Are there around better solutions to that problem?
3- Is there any way to have already build .DAEs for the single characters ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `extrusiondepth` paramater of SCNText to make it look more '3D':

> **Apple:**  For example, if its extrusionDepth property is 1.0, the geometry extends from -0.5 to 0.5 along the z-axis. An extrusion depth of zero creates a flat, one-sided shape—the geometry is confined to the plane whose z-coordinate is 0.0, and viewable only from its front unless its material’s isDoubleSided property is true.

You can also use an `NSAttributedString` which would add some extra' effects'.

And finally you say that you want the SCNText to appear dynamically based on Keyboard input?

Create a `TextField` and add it to your view e.g:

```
    let textField =  UITextField(frame: self.view.bounds)
    self.view.addSubview(textField)
    textField.backgroundColor = .clear
    textField.becomeFirstResponder()
    textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
```

Respond to the input:

```
 @objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {

  //Set The SCNText Here

   displayLabel.string = textField.text

}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I am already implementing SCNText with extrusiondepth, but I do not like the result, that's why I am checking for other methods. My idea is to map every character to a single DAE and put a node for every single DAE. I think this can be done with less pain in another way that actually I am yet not aware of.

Comment: I would say that that would be unmanageable if you are going to do multiple languages...